# Receive /Send data through Wifi under Windows Mobile 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a desktop client application build under .net 4.0 and WPF.
In this application I need to send /Receive data from a client app on a Windows Mobile, this would be through Wifi.

I have no deep experience on this and would like to here your advise or approach on how to do it.

I already done such scenario throuh a wire network between different client through a `WCF service` hosted under a `Server2008` but would like to do a be directionnal sync app between phone and my client.

Could you post me some ideas or sample approach?
thnaks for help
sergeenter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out servicestack.  http://servicestack.net/.  Pretty simple to get up and running on the server and client side.  There isn't a WP7 client for it, yet but RestSharp works fine.

[Sample](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Examples/ServiceStack.Examples.Host.Console) of how you might host in a WPF app: